# Attempt to read property "id" on int

Tags: laravel

i hope someone can help me with this error

when the leave_admin table has no record, this error will prompt.
this is for leave view

the error was vague and i am beginner in laravel, i hope you guys can help me.

[image]

this is my controller code

```
    public function leaves()
{
    $leaves = DB::table('leaves_admin')
        ->join('users', 'users.rec_id', '=', 'leaves_admin.rec_id')
        ->select('leaves_admin.*','users.role_name','users.name','users.avatar')
        ->get();
        
    return view('leave.leaves',compact('leaves'));
}

    public function approved($id)
{   
    try{
        $leaves = LeaveAdmin::find($id);
        $leaves->status='Approved';
        $leaves->save();

        DB::commit();
        Toastr::success('Leave Request Approve Successfully','Success');
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        
        DB::rollback();
        Toastr::error('Failed to Approve Request','Error');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/leaves/new', 'leaves')->middleware('auth')->name('LeavesNew');
Route::get('/leaveApprove/{id}', 'approved')->middleware('auth')->name('Approved');
```

This is my view

```
 <!-- Approve Leave Modal -->
    <div class="modal custom-modal fade" id="approve_leave" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-header">
                        <h3>Leave Status</h3>
                        <p>What do you want to do with this request?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-btn delete-action">                            
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a href="{{ route('Approved', $leaves->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary continue-btn">Approve</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary cancel-btn">Reject</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `leaves()` function, you are returning to the view the variable `$leaves` that is a collection instance.

So, in your view, when you do `$leaves->id` it will throw an error due to the fact that the id should exist in each element of the collection, not in the collection itself.

You need to first [loop](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops) into the collection, and just then access the property:

```
@foreach($leaves as $leave)
// ...
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="{{ route('Approved', $leave->id) }}" class="...">Approve</a>
</div>
//...
@endforeach
```

Comment: after i implement this, i just get another error

'Attempt to read property "id" on int'

Comment: Inspect what is the content of each `$leave` first